# Get user ID - WebAPI Spotify (Spotipy)

Tags: spotify, spotipy

my question
is possible get a user id in any way? I would search a user from his name and print his recently artist played

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible due to Spotify's Web API has no endpoint where you can fetch user ids by their names.

---

What you can do is creating an application where a specific user can login using Spotify. Afterwards you can use [this](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/player/get-recently-played/) endpoint in order to retrieve the recently played tracks of that exact user. The track object in the response will hold the artist as well.